# Replace full line of PHP in another file

Tags: php, pdo

I would like to update a database configuration file dynamically. First, I copy theme files over from one directory to another directory. These theme files contain a database configuration file.

After the files are copied over, I would like to update the database configuration file to use the name of the new database that was created (using $dbname).

```
$dbname = "Database 1"; 

$data = file('file.php'); // reads an array of lines
function replace_a_line($data) {
   if (stristr($data, 'dbname=')) {
     return 'dbname=' . $dbname . '';
   }
   return $data;
}
$data = array_map('replace_a_line',$data);
file_put_contents('file.php', implode('', $data));
```

file.php:

```
$this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=', '', '');
```

My problem with the function above is that it replaces the entire line with just

```
dbname=
```

I don't know how to use return with the proper syntax to add that full line of php

I need it to look like this:

```
$this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=test', '', '');
```

What can I use to retain the original php line and just add to dbname= ?

What if I replaced the line with an entire file that just contained the above line of PHP that way I can insert the whole PHP line?

Comment: Don't you think there's a better way of doing this? I can't see your database settings file, but how about passing in `$dbname` as an argument to some function, and fill it in when the function is executed in your database settings file?

Comment: yea this is kind of my first go around with creating databases dynamically so I am open to and appreciate the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some corrections in your code to make it works as you expect:

```
$data = file('file.php'); // reads an array of lines
function replace_a_line($data) {
   $dbname = "Database 1";
   if (stristr($data, 'dbname=')) {
     return str_replace('dbname=', 'dbname=' . $dbname, $data);

   }
   return $data;
}
$data = array_map('replace_a_line',$data);
file_put_contents('file.php', implode('', $data));
```

Comment: That makes the line disappear completely

Comment: No errors but now it's not altering the line at all

Comment: Im wondering if file permissions need altering. Its 644 right now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overthinking this a little bit.

Here is my suggestion, create a config file containing your database settings

```
$config = array(
    // These are the settings for development mode
    'development' => array(

        'db' => array(
            'host'     => 'xxxx',
            'dbname'   => 'yyyy',
            'username' => 'xxx',
            'password' => 'zzzzz',
            ),       
        ),

    // These are the settings for production mode
    'production' => array(

        'db' => array(
            'host'     => 'xzzz',
            'dbname'   => 'fsfs',
            'username' => 'dsdsd',
            'password' => 'xsscsc',
            ),
        ),
    );
```

And you would use dynamically by passing different configuration to your db class constructor:

```
class Database{
    include("config.php");   
    private $pdo;
    private $config;

    // constructor
    function __construct($mode) {           
        $this->config = $config[$mode];
    }


    public function get_connection(){
        $this->pdo = new PDO(
            'mysql:host=' . $this->config['db']['host'].';dbname=' . $this->config['db']['dbname'], 
            $this->config['db']['username'], 
            $this->config['db']['password'],
            array());

        // If there is an error executing database queries, we want PDO to
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        return $this->pdo;
    }

   public function __destruct(){
        $this->pdo = null;
   }

}
```

Usage :

```
$db = new Database('production');
$pdo = $db->get_connection();
```

Comment: Please see my edits to the original question. I need to be able to replace $dbname in the configuration file since I'm copying over theme files that contain the configuration file.